# Can we cookie or save public vs private display when opening Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible or could you guys please think about providing a cookie mechanism or a way to save whether you were last on the public site, or the private team, or the general (both) for teams?

[image]

This way upon returning to the site it remembers which area I was last in?

Comment: @Script47 Meta and main already have different URLs, no need for the browser to remember anything. If I'm going to meta, I do not want to be redirected to main because I visited that last, nor vice-versa. I do not know if teams have different URLs making this distinction necessary or not.

Comment: @yivi Good point, you are quite correct.

Comment: Why can't you just bookmark the `/c/channel-name` URL?

Comment: @Undo Bookmark, what's that? `/s` hate having to bookmark it all